# Why does Xcode's new build system have trouble compiling targets in parallel?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, build

We have a CMake-generated C++ project with > 300 targets.

Recently, I started trying the Xcode "new build system", introduced since Xcode 10 (mainly because CMake started using the "new build system" as a default setting)

I noticed approx. 20% slower build times and found that in the new build system, there is much less parallel building of targets. Using the legacy build system, most of the time I see more than 5 targets being compiled in parallel. Using the new build system, there are long periods with only one concurrently compiled target, so my 10 cores run out of work during linking.

Here's a typical CPU load history for the legacy build system...

[image: cpu stays at 100 percent all the time]

... while the next image shows a typical CPU load history using the new build system:

[image: cpu load keeps low during linking phases]

The only difference between the images is a change to the legacy build system in File -> Project Settings... in Xcode.

The new build system is advertised as "faster builds for Swift projects". So:

- Are there any known caveats using the new build system, e.g. hidden dependencies?
- are there any other experiences with c++ projects?

Comment: There are a load of caveats listed in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/build-system-release-notes-for-xcode-10). Did you check those already?

Comment: Thanks for pointing. Can't see any immediate issues affecting us. Under "new features" they state "While a target is performing post-compilation build steps, such as linking ..., Xcode’s new build system will begin compiling sources from targets that depend on that target, ... This compilation will not start until any “Run Script” phases from the target have completed." This could mean a) that the new build system identifies more inter-target dependencies or b) that the legacy system does not wait for the "Run script" phases before starting compilation of the next target.

Comment: Yeah, possibly - so if you have a long run-script phase after linking I guess that might affect it